# Installing Eclipse using MacPorts

Tags: eclipse, macports

I'm learning my way around MacPorts, so I've been trying to use it to install all kinds of things. I noticed it has a port for Eclipse, so I installed it using

```
sudo port install eclipse-ecj32
```

And that installed the port and all its dependencies. But I have no clue what to do now! I don't see it installed in my LaunchPad anywhere.

Sooooo... what do I do? How do I make eclipse run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is [**not available via MacPorts**](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=category&substr=eclipse).  Likely this is because a native version is available to [**download for Mac**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx).

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the actual IDE, thats the byte-code compiler... So its not a GUI application, its just a jar of the compiler i believe.

Comment: So does that mean I need to go to the Eclipse webpage and download the IDE? Any recommendations on a good package to install for Python development? Apparently I want PyDev. And... what do I do with the byte-code compiler?